# Why are there two "Where in the World?" hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2019

Why are there two "Where in the world?" and is it possible to earn both on different sites?

I got the same "Moon" on different sites, and it displayed once unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know why there are two forms (North and South of the equator?) but you can only get one form and it is intentional. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%ef%b8%8f-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f I assume that holds across all sites on Exchange.

Comment: [It [was\] not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289057/would-it-have-been-possible-to-get-both-versions-of-where-in-the-world-with-an) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288457/why-are-there-two-different-hats-for-where-in-the-world?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Kaiido thank you for those links. Silly that I could not find them myself

Comment: I love the Solstice (Where in the world?) hats! [I got the sunshine hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341041/395288).